# Install APK in the background programmatically

Tags: android, installation, apk

I am trying to install a APK on android in the background. When I `pm install -r /storage/emulated/0/tmp/demo.apk` directly on the shell it installs the APK without root.

But when I try to do it programmatically it doesn't work. This is the code that I use:

```
try {
    String command = "pm install -r /storage/emulated/0/tmp/demo.apk";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    process.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Are there any special permissions that I need to use to get this to work

Comment: and thanks God that it doesn't work (and won't work). **There is no way to install APK in background without root**. More - there should be no way, since only the user can decide if he needs that app, or not. Not you, not anyone else.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I forgot to mention this is for a service for android tablets to go into prisons which runs a custom android firmware. Is there any way to add to the OS any exception.

Comment: you can install root access by default to your firmware, or install your main app as a system app. After that you'll be able to install in background

Comment: @VladMatvienko This is for our voicemail app for the prisoners and we want the device to auto update the voicemail app automatically.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Do I just need to make this a system app. Then what permissions do I need to install the app. After that can I just run that code.

Comment: then you can embedde your `voicemail app` into your firmware as a system app. After that you can install apps in background

Comment: you should be able to just run the code AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for your help, will give it a go.